# $filter('filter') with multiple expressions and conditions

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filtering

ok... I'm working on a real estate page for a client and I need a filter that filters based on what the user has selected, e.g. rent/buy/appartment/house

Currently this is my function

```
    $scope.$watch('propfilters', function () {

    if( typeof $scope.propfilters != "undefined" ) 
    {
        var filterstr = buildfilter($scope.propfilters);
        $scope.filteredtodos = $filter('filter')($scope.master, {Filters : filterstr});
        $scope.totallistings = $scope.filteredtodos.length;
    }
},true);
```

and this is buildfilter

```
function buildfilter(str)
{
    var filt = [];
    var cty = '';
    var filter='';
    var i = 0;

    if (str.City !== false && typeof str.City != "undefined"){cty = '{city : "'+str.City+'"} && ';}
    if (str.Buy === true && typeof str.Buy != "undefined"){filt.push(" {Buy : true} ");i++;}
    if (str.Rent === true && typeof str.Rent != "undefined"){filt.push(" {Rent : true} ");i++;}
    if (str.OfferHouse === true && typeof str.OfferHouse != "undefined"){filt.push(" {OfferHouse : true} ");i++;}
    if (str.OfferApartment === true && typeof str.OfferApartment != "undefined"){filt.push(" {OfferApartment : true} ");i++;}
    var tmp = '';
    tmp = filt.join(" || ");
    filter = cty.concat(tmp);

    return filter;
}
```

Here is my issue when just 1 filter is selected it works great but when multiple are selected, it breaks the `$filter('filter')` function

But there are conditions that need to be met in this ... if the city is set all matches have to be in the city whether rent buy..(etc) and any of the other options can be true and if so show .. I had a filter 805 working but it was over 105 lines of code... any ideas?

Comment: so your filter is not working for multiple selection, right?

Comment: basically i was trying to use $filter('filter') to filter based on the values but i think i may need a better way

Comment: so, you are displaying the data in table and for each column, you have a filter which will filter that particular data in the column, right?

Comment: the display is not even formatted yet im trying to get the filters to remove the array objects that don't match the conditions of the filters